# Java typecasting and raw types

Tags: java, generics, casting

GeneratedMessage.Builder is a **static nested** class inside GeneratedMessage (both of them are abstract classes). When the method `build()` is called on an object of type GeneratedMessage.Builder, it returns an object of type GeneratedMessage. Is there some way to declare my raw types `T` and `B` in the following example, which would make the typecasting in the return statement of `convert()` needless.

```
public class JsonStringToMessageConverter<T extends GeneratedMessage, B extends GeneratedMessage.Builder<B>>
        implements IConverter<String, T> {
  private final IPbBuilderProvider<B> m_builderProvider;

  @Inject
  public JsonStringToMessageConverter(IPbBuilderProvider<B> builderProvider) {
    m_builderProvider = builderProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public final T convert(String value) {
    B builder = m_builderProvider.getPbBuilder();
    try {
      JsonFormat.merge(value, builder);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new LoggedRuntimeException(ErrorType.PARSE_FAILED, e);
    }
    return (T) builder.build();
  }
}
```

The class `GeneratedMessage` is defined in Google's Protobuf library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use type parameter in the `Builder` for `build()` method return type and declare it as `extends GeneratedMessage`.

As I see the [build method](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message.Builder.html#build%28%29) is not generic, so you cannot do it, I'm afraid.

Comment: The `Message.Builder` class, in which `build()` is defined is not generic.

Comment: I thought your original post requested a copy of the code, not a statement that the class was not generic. Sorry if my comment was pre-edit or I was incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand your answer about using a type parameter for the `build` method since it is not generic. Would you please explain?

Comment: I mean it's how _should_ be to make it work. But as it's a 3rd party library and it doesn't define generics as should, it's impossible to avoid using unchecked casts, because potentially the library may return any `Message` form the method, so the type should be checked in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not since the `build` method is defined within the `Message.Builder` class and that class is not generic. The `build` method returns a `Message` object not some generic extension of the `Message` class. Therefore there is no generic manipulation of `GeneratedMessage.Builder` that will cause the method signature of `build` return anything other than `Message`.